# Can we maintain DNS records of a particular domain from different places?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, registrar

I have bought a domain from BigRock and there are some DNS record entries in BigRock.
And I'm using AWS Route53 service (DNS Service only) for the above domain and was maintaining some different records.

Is this doable?

If yes, what will happen if I have same DNS record entries at both places, does the request go to entry in BigRock or to the entry in Route53?

If no, what will happen if I add the Nameservers created by Route53 (during the creation of Hosted Zone) in BigRock and keeping the existing Name servers provided by BigRock?

Please add in your detailed explanation

Comment: what's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1):

Route53 is DNS management service, delegating specific domain from Bigrock to Route 53 allows the ability to create dynamic environments with the tools provided by Amazon Web Services. Once you delegate to AWS, you cannot control your DNS from Bigrock.

You can also delegate a specific sub-domain to be managed by route53. For example, sub-domain mail.example.com can be delegated to route 53, while the parent domain example.com can be managed from BigRock.

Comment: what will happen if I have duplicate entries of sub domain at both places?It also means that Big rock has its own Name servers along with Route53 Name servers right

Comment: you can have entries in only in one place, once you transfer the domain to route 53, you lose control in bigrock.

Comment: If I transfer the domain to Route53 then your point is valid. In my case I did not transfer and just created hosted zone in Route53 with my domain name and Route53 creates 4 name servers by default. 
I have added the 4 name servers in big rock.

Comment: Sorry. Transfer is not the right word, In that case, you cant use big rock to manage your DNS anymore, Can you still edit the records in Bigrock? i don't think so.

Comment: I'm not using the DNS service of BigRock. Since I'm doing one of the POC on AWS, so do not want to experiment it right now. I'm not sure what will happen if I add Big rock Name servers along with Route53 name servers.